# Update Parse-Server-Example

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-server

I thought it would be a topic to find easily on the web, but I couldnt find a solution..

I deployed the parse-server-example on AWS Elastic Beanstalk according to the original documentation and it works perfectly. Can anyone give me a hint how to update this server to the newest version? I try to use the parse-dashboard and I get the error "server version too low".

I cloned the parse server with eb cli already. But I do not know how / which files to update.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In package.json, you update the version next to 'parse-server'. I think by default this is '~2.0'?

Parse Dashboard requires Parse-Server to be '>=2.1.4', HOWEVER, currently I'm having issues when changing the parse-server version, it breaks my AWS server instance. Currently have an issue open on GitHub (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example/issues/109#issuecomment-198001722), so keep an eye on that.

But yeah, that's where you update your Parse-Server version, I believe!

Once you've done this locally on your machine, you obviously need to deploy the updates to AWS via the Beanstalk Dashboard, as this will install/update any node modules from package.json.

Comment: Hi, thanks that helped. As you said, this works locally as expected but does not on the server. I will track the github issue.